# Minimize and ParametricNDSolve

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I'm trying to fit an observed orbit

```
data={years,xobs,dx,yobs,dy}
```

where xobs and yobs are the observed coordinates and dx,dy the corresponding errors. I must fit this orbit with solutions coming from two differential equations

```
Eq1=x''[t]=f[x,y]
Eq2=y''[t]=g[x,y]
```

I want to build a chi square variable and to minimize it over four parameters (initial conditions on position and velocities). I wrote the following code:

```
ss = ParametricNDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, x[1992.22] == x0, 
x'[1992.22] == vx0*(yr/AU), y[1992.22] == y0, 
y'[1992.22] == vy0*(yr/AU)}, {x, y}, {t, 1992.22, 
2009.61}, {x0, vx0, y0, vy0}, 
Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, 
Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
PrecisionGoal -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

X[tt_] = x[tt] /. ss /. tt -> t;
Y[tt_] = y[tt] /. ss /. tt -> t;
xconv[tt_] = ((c1*X[tt]) + (c2*Y[tt]))/. ss[[1]] /. tt -> t;
yconv[tt_] = ((d1*X[tt]) + (d2*Y[tt])) /. ss[[1]] /. tt -> t;
```

where ci,di are given constants. The function to minimize is:

```
chisquare[x0_?NumberQ, vx0_?NumberQ, y0_?NumberQ, vy0_?NumberQ] := 
1/(70 - 2)
Sum[(((xconv[t = years[[i]]] - xobs[[i]])/(dx[[i]] 2))^2 + ((
yconv[t = years[[i]]] - yobs[[i]])/(dy[[i]] 2)))^2, {i, 1, 70}]

NMinimize[
chisquare[x0, vx0, y0, 
vy0], {{x0 > 850}, {vx0 > 600}, {y0 > 1570}, {vy0 > 50}}, {x0, vx0, 
y0, vy0}]
```

But I get several error messages

```
Hold::fpct: -- Message text not found -- ({x0,vx0,y0,vy0}) ({1992.22}) >>
the function value ...
is not a number at {vx0,vy0,x0,y0} = \
{601.4626035460618`,51.586099690163145`,851.0994304457607`,1571.\
9647629127392`}. >>
The function value 1...is not a number at {vx0,vy0,x0,y0} = {601.463,51.5861,851.099,1571.96}. >>
```

Is this the right way or is there something completely wrong in the syntax?

EDIT1:

I modified a little the code and now it is running but it's too slow.

Comment: I am wondering that this runs. Eq1 reads: x''[t]=f[x,y].  It should read: x''[t]==f[x[t],y[t]] e.t.c.  If x and y are functions,  they need an argument. Further, the first is an assignment, not an equation. Then you should give some data, in order that people are able to run your code.

Comment: I solved it modifying a bit the code. Then, I put Minimize in a table because I must find the best fit initial conditions for different choices of some parameters. But it takes a very long time.